# PnP JS handle error if case "overwrite: false" enters

Tags: javascript, typescript, sharepoint, pnp-js

My Code:

```
try{
    if (file.size <= 1048) {
    result = await sp.web.lists
    .getByTitle(documentLibraryTitle)
    .rootFolder.files.addUsingPath(fileNamePath, file, { Overwrite: false });
    } 
    else{
       throw new Error(`The filename already exists!`);
    }
} catch (err) {
              console.error("something went wrong", err);
              throw new Error("something went wrong");
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is, if the case ***"Overwrite:false"*** (=Trying to upload an existing File with same Name) ...enters, i want to return the first error inside the else brackets.

Instead of that as result i always get the error inside the catch brackets.
Anyone have an idea to fix this behaving?

Comment: Just wondering why you are checking the size of the file you are uploading? Shouldn't you check that the file exists instead?

Comment: because there is another variation for uploading larger files.

Comment: I mean, your "else" branch will only execute when your file is less than 1Kb. It does not seem to be bound to file existence in any way. Is it some sort of typo?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but thats not even relevant for the question i've been asking. 
I will change the size afterwards probably. Its just for testing purposes.

Comment: My issue is that the code above calls the last error all the time

Comment: Yes, this is correct. When you disable overwrite, and the file exists, you get an exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could think of two options. First option: you check that the file exists before trying to overwrite it, and if it does, then throw your error. Second option: you analyze the pnpjs error message, and if is about file being already there, throw your error message.

First:

```
const exists = await sp.web.lists
  .getByTitle(documentLibraryTitle).rootFolder.files
  .getByName(fileNamePath) // or .getByUrl()
  .exists();

if (exists) {
  throw new Error(`The filename already exists!`);
}

// ... upload file like you do now ...
```

Second:

```
try {

  await sp.web.lists
    .getByTitle(documentLibraryTitle).rootFolder.files
    .addUsingPath(fileNamePath, file, { Overwrite: false });

} catch (e) {

      // see "error handling in pnpjs"
      // https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/concepts/error-handling/#reading-the-response

      if (e.isHttpRequestError) {

        // get the response
        const data = await e.response.json();

        // fetch error code
        const code = typeof data["odata.error"] === "object" ? data["odata.error"].code : null;

        // it's about overwrite
        if (code === '-2130575257, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException') {
          throw new Error(`The filename already exists!`);
        }
      }
    }
}
```